# Поиск всех слов начинающихся с буквы 'c'

Tags: python, python-3.5

нужно использую функцию findall найти в тексте все слова начинающиеся на букву 'c'. Плохо понимаю в регулярных выражениях, поэтому прошу помощи разобраться. Спасибо

///
Я просто не понимаю как можно в выражение задать динамический размер слова, которые нужно найти.

`result = re.findall(r'c...\b',s)` - так бы я делал, если бы искал слово начинающиеся с "с" и имеющие еще 3 символа после. Но как задать универсальный размер я не понимаю.

**Ответ на вопрос:** `result = re.findall(r"\bc\w*\b",s)`

как по мне намного проще, чем советовали люди писать циклами

Comment: Напишите хотя бы примерный алгоритм, как вы себе представляете работу программы. Пример кода, написанного вами, тоже не помешает.

Comment: Предложенный ответ найдет *все* слова *содержащие* букву `c`, а не начинающиеся с нее. В принципе, использовать в такой задаче регулярки имеет смысл только в случае, если цель - изучение регулярок. Проще в каком смысле? Однозначно не проще в смысле эффективностию

Comment: У вас неверное регулярное выражение

Comment: не следует ответ помещать в вопрос. Если думаете, что нашли решение, [опубликуйте его как свой ответ (и можете его позже принять, если он самый полезный для вас)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 3):

Решить такую простую задачу можно и без регулярных выражений

```
words = []
for line in open('text.txt'):
    words += [w for w in line.split() if w.startswith('c')]
```

Но если нужно именно с их помощью, то `re.findall(r'\bc\w+\b', s)`.

Comment: спасибо, конечно. Мб здесь и регулярные выражения не нужны, но задание именно такое. Это нужно для тренировки и понимания принципов, и вы мне даете как не то.

Comment: @RomanAlexandrovich,  “Если у вас есть проблема и вы решили использовать регулярные выражения, у вас уже две проблемы”

Comment: Задание задано вам, а вы его почему-то перепоручаете нам.

Comment: `\w` - отнюдь не "только буквы"))

Comment: @andy.37 ваша правда, исправил.

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример решения

```
import re

lines = ['тест', 'сова', 'Call', 'string', 'Свет', 'box', 'cute']

for line in lines:
    if re.match(r'\b[c|с][а-яa-z]*\b', line, re.IGNORECASE):
        print(line)
```

Почитайте о регулярных выражениях чуть больше [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/115825/) и [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/115436/)

Answer (score -1):

```
result = re.findall(r'c\w*',string)
```

c - та самая первая буква (только проверь, русская с тебе нужна или английская, тут английская)
\w - все буквы
* - ноль или более

Comment: \w* будет брать не только буквы

Comment: \w будет будет брать непробельные символы что и даст слова.

Comment: Он будет брать и числа тоже

Comment: Если числа будут начинаться на букву с, то да.

Comment: Такая регулярка найдёт строку ```c1jk```, например. Не очень похоже на слово